# How can i reset a select box when i select an empty value of another select box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two select boxes. How can i reset the second select box every time i select an empty value at the first select box using jquery? Here's the code:

```js
if( $('#regionId').val() ) { 
$('#cityId').val()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="regionId" id="regionId" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">
<option value="">Select a region...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">California</option>
<option value="3">New York</option>
</select>


<select name="cityId" id="cityId" aria-invalid="true" class="valid">
<option value="">Select a city...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="6">Miami</option>
<option value="7" >New Jersey</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for the changing of the `#regionId` control...

```
$(function() {
  $("#regionId").on("click", function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

You then need to check the value to see if it's empty... and if it is you need to **set** the empty value to `#cityId`...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#regionId").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") { 
      $("#cityId").val("")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="regionId" id="regionId" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">
<option value="">Select a region...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">California</option>
<option value="3">New York</option>
</select>


<select name="cityId" id="cityId" aria-invalid="true" class="valid">
<option value="">Select a city...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="6">Miami</option>
<option value="7" >New Jersey</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to make your city dropdown empty when the region is empty.

```js
function update(elem){
  if($(elem).val() == ""){
    $("#cityId").val("").change();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="regionId" id="regionId" aria-invalid="false" class="valid" onchange="update(this)">
<option value="">Select a region...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">California</option>
<option value="3">New York</option>
</select>


<select name="cityId" id="cityId" aria-invalid="true" class="valid">
<option value="">Select a city...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="6">Miami</option>
<option value="7" >New Jersey</option>
</select>
```